# time difference between my and betfair server

Tags: php, time, betfair

There is about 38-40 seconds difference between my and betfair server time.
I don't want to use some dec/inc in my time to manage.i want to be sync with betfair server time.
Please Help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Finally, if you want to synchronise your request counting with Betfair's time, please note the following list of Network Time Protocol (NTP) servers Betfair uses:
 - Chimera.csx.cam.ac.uk
 - Ntp.maths.tcd.ie
 - Dire.bris.ac.uk
 - Ntp1.pipex.net
```

http://bdp.betfair.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=241&Itemid=68